# Euler Method implementation in Python gives a stable result but it should be unstable

Tags: python-3.x, numerical-methods, differential-equations, numerical-analysis, numerical-stability

I am trying to solve this differential equation with the Euler Method using Python3:

[image]

According to Wolfram Alpha, that's the plot of the correct equation.

[image]

Again, according to Wolfram Alpha, in this case, the classic Euler Method should **not** be stable, as you can see by the end of the interval:

[image]

However, on my implementation, Euler method provides a stable result, which **is strange**. I wonder that my implementation is wrong for some reason. Nonetheless, I can't find the error.

I generated some points and a plot comparing my approximation and the analytic output of the function. In blue, the analytic result as control group. In red, the output of my implementation:

[image]

That's my code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pylab

def f(x):

    return (math.e)**(-10*x)

def euler(x):

    y_init = 1
    x_init = 0

    old_dy_dx = -10*y_init

    old_y = y_init 

    new_y = None

    new_dy_dx = None

    delta_x = 0.001

    limite = 0

    while x>limite:

        #for i in range(1,6):

        new_y = delta_x*old_dy_dx + old_y
        #print ("new_y", new_y)

        new_dy_dx = -10*new_y
        #print ("new dy_dx", new_dy_dx)

        old_y = new_y
        #print ("old_y", old_y)

        old_dy_dx = new_dy_dx
        #print ("old delta y_delta x", old_dy_dx)
        #print ("iterada",i)

        limite = limite +delta_x

    return new_y

t = np.linspace(-1,5, 80)

lista_outputs = []

for i in t:
    lista_outputs.append(euler(i))
    print (i)

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
plt.plot(t, f(t), 'b-', label='Output resultado analítico')
plt.plot(t , lista_outputs, 'ro', label="Output resultado numérico")
plt.title('Comparação Euler/Analítico - tolerância: 0.3')
pylab.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Thanks for the help.

============================================================

**UPDATE**

With @SourabhBhat help, I was able to see that my implementation was, actually, right. It was, indeed, generating an instability. Besides increasing the step size, I needed to do some zoom in to see it happening.

The picture bellow speaks for itself (step size of 0.22):

[image]

Comment: Do not use `math.e**(-10*x)`, use `np.exp(-10*x)` as `a^b` is implemented as `exp(b*log(a))` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the time step size, the Euler integration can be stable or unstable, since it is an explicit method. You have chosen a pretty small time step. If you increase it you will start seeing the oscillations, as shown in figure below.

[image: Oscillations]

Here is a small testing program which I wrote (try slowly increasing the `steps` variable [20,30,40,50....]):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

steps = 20


def exact_solution(t):
    return np.exp(-10.0 * t)


def numerical_solution(y0, dt, num_steps):
    y = np.zeros(num_steps + 1)
    y[0] = y0
    for step in range(num_steps):
        y[step + 1] = y[step] - 10.0 * y[step] * dt

    return y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t0 = 0
    time = np.linspace(t0, 5, steps + 1)
    num_sol = numerical_solution(exact_solution(t0), time[1] - time[0], steps)
    exact_sol = exact_solution(time)

    plt.plot(time, num_sol, ".--", label="numerical")
    plt.plot(time, exact_sol, label="exact")
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me! I did what you said and increased my step to 0.9. I also increased the interval from 0 until 50 in order to see things better. However, my implementation does **not** generate an oscillation! It generates a monotonic error downward. Do you have any insight about why this happens?    Thanks for your code. But I would really like to understand why my implementation fails.

Comment: In your code also, for delta_x = 0.22 and above I can see visible oscillations. I am using Python 3.

Comment: Oh, yeah! You are right. The oscillations are actually **happening* on my implementation, they were just pretty small, I was not seeing them! Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical problem from numerical analysis. Euler’s method is only unstable if your stepsize is too large. The exact solution to your differential equation is:

y(t) = exp(-10t)*y(0)

that is your initial data simply gets multiplied by exp(-10t), which is always a number such that 0 < exp(-10t) < 1. Thus your result gets smaller.

Euler’s method for a single time-step yields:

y(t + dt) = (1-10dt)*y(t)

Thus, your data simply gets multiplied by (1-10dt). You want that 0 < (1-10dt) < 1, to mimic the original ODE. That is:

0 < dt < 1/10

**If you choose your step-size in this range, Euler’s method will be stable.**

Larger dt will cause the factor (1-10*dt) to become negative, and your solution will change its sign after every step. Choosing dt even larger, dt > 2/10 will cause your solution to grow exponentially, because then |1-10*dt| > 1.

An implicit method can allow you to bypass this time-step constraint.